# creating a batch file to run different codes sequentially

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im trying to create a .bat file with with different codes, each of these codes exceute different commands, but I don't want to run them separately but in one batch file.

All my batch codes that excute different things can they be linked together in one batch file and the codes can be ran sequentially by using call commmand by simply adding it to the start of code for eg
This is example of the bat file

```
Start 

call @echo off (These three lines are code2) 
:h cmd /c start /MAX /HIGH tree c:\

Call code 3 etc is that right
```

So I just need to add call to the start of the batch codes and each different code saved in one file with execute one after the other sequentially simply by adding call to the start of the code?

Comment: I couldn't even understand your question until I read the first line of @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would like to run multiple batch files sequentially from your master batch file.

You can save your batch files like file1.bat file2.bat and your master batch file as master.bat

run the other batch files in your master file sequentially as

```
echo calling sequential process 1
call file1.bat
echo calling sequential process 2
call file2.bat
```

When you use call control will return to your caller once the called bat completes. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do but I don't want to create different files is there a way I can just create one .bat file with all the commands..I'm a beginner so I apologise for my knowledge in this area, basically I have 5,batch commands which execute different functions I want to add them all into one file so they run sequentially, is there a command I can add to the start of each different commands so they will execute one after the other?

Answer (score 1):

To get started, please use the term "Commands" instead of "Codes".

> So I just need to add call to the start of the batch codes and each different code saved in one file with execute one after the other sequentially simply by adding call to the start of the code?

In general, yes that's right. A batch file runs a series of commands in order. Add your commands to the batch file, and then run the batch file.

Beyond that, there is a lot wrong with your example...

The use of `call` in your example is wrong.  In the command prompt type `call /?`:

> Calls one batch program from another.

Not sure if your example contains "Start" because you want to show the start of the example, or if you're actual trying to use the `Start` command.  If so, you're not using it correctly either.

From `Start /?`:

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

I'm also not sure why you have a label named "h" (`:h`), when you're not referencing it anyplace else, and I'm not sure why you would run `CMD` with `start` as an argument.  Very seldom will you need to run `cmd` from within a batch file.

Anyhow, hope these pointers help get you going.

Example:

```
@echo off
c:
cd\
c:\path\program.exe
"c:\other Path with spaces\SecondProgram.exe"
call c:\path\AnotherBatchFile.bat
start /wait "c:\some path\ProgramYouWantToWaitToFinishBeforeContinuing.exe"
d:\
ProgramInRootOfD.exe
cd\temp
del /q *.*
```

Comment: I'm a beginner so I apologise for my knowledge in this area, basically I have 5,batch commands which execute different functions I want to add them all into one file so they run sequentially, is there a command I can add to the start of each different commands so they will execute one after the other?

Comment: `Call`: "Calls One Batch Program From Another". :)

Comment: @Beginner If the command you want to launch form the batch file are not other batch files, then just put the commands in the batch file directly, and don't use CALL or START unless you find you need to for some reason.

Comment: If the command you want to launch form the batch file are not other batch files, then just put the commands in the batch file directly, and don't use CALL or START unless you find you need to for some reason..

Comment: The files are batch files, is there no way to link different command in one batch file ie add all the commands in one file so each command code runs sequentially in one batch file?

Comment: Sure, create a new batch file, and then just copy the contents from the other batch files into it, in the order you'd like and save it.  If the batch files are sufficiently complex (loops, jumps, labels, etc.) then you will have to be cautious, as to avoid execution flow problems, duplicate labels, etc. introduced by combining them.

Comment: I have copied them into one file but is there any command I can add to the start of the command so I know it will run? I have one batch file with 5 different commands is there anything I add to the beginning of the code to ensure it will be exceute?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, all commands in the batch will run (unless you have logic in there to skip them).

Comment: I have copied all the different commands and put them in one file so is that all I need todo, not add any additional commands to the start of each separate batch code, so I ensure they exceute  from that file that contains all the commands?